# Organize Posts Into 3 Columns

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to organize posts into three columns, but I can't get it to work. I just want to display 3 posts in 3 different columns.

So

1 | 2 | 3

What I have so far:

```
<div id="main-wrapper">

<?php 
  $loop = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'camp', 'posts_per_page' => 3)); 
  if ($loop->have_posts()) ?>
    <?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
    <?php   
    $custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);
    $screenshot_url = $custom["screenshot_url"][0];
    $website_url = $custom["website_url"][0];
?>


 <?php the_content(); ?>


<?php endwhile; ?>


</div>
```

site is [Botkai](http://www.botkai.com/camps-page/)

Comment: are you getting three posts stacked on top one another with your code above?

Comment: I haven't added the content in the code above, but yes, that's what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can easily be done by creating another DIVs inside parent

```
<div id="main-wrapper">

<?php 
  $loop = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'camp', 'posts_per_page' => 3)); 
  if ($loop->have_posts()) ?>
    <?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
    <div style="float: left;"> <!-- or other class that contains this CSS property, including width etc. -->
      <?php   
        $custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);
        $screenshot_url = $custom["screenshot_url"][0];
        $website_url = $custom["website_url"][0];
      ?>
    </div>


<?php endwhile; ?>


</div>
```

Comment: I was going to suggest something very similar. The idea is to wrap each post in its own container as it comes out.

Comment: Try using margin or padding CSS property